# create toolbar imagelist with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, toolbars

I'd like to use the ImageMagick `convert` tool to automatically generate a toolbar bitmap from several png images.

I'm using the following command line:

```
convert.exe -resize 32x32 @imagelist32.txt +append BMP3:toolbarlarge.bmp
```

with `imagelist32.txt` containing a list of png files (each one being one toolbar button).

This works, but the resulting bitmap uses black for the transparent color and white as the background color. I would need both colors to be RGB(192,192,192). Like if there was already an image with that background color, and the png images would be drawn on that background.

How can I do that? I've tried adding the `-background #C0C0C0` and `-transparent-color #C0C0C0` parameters but it didn't work - maybe I put them in the wrong order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you've probably resolved it by your own, but I've been playing a bit with converter.exe some time ago, so I hope this is what you were looking for.

Set the `-alpha` parameter to the `background` flag, what means that every fully transparent pixel will be set to the background color, while leaving it fully transparent.
And set also the `-background` to a certain color `RGB(192,192,192)`, so the previously transparent pixels will get this color.

```
convert.exe -resize 32x32 -alpha background -background RGB(192,192,192) @imagelist32.txt +append BMP3:toolbarlarge.bmp
```